# Converting MathML to LaTeX: limits position on summation symbol

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, typography, mathml

When using  [David Carlisle's stylesheet](https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/tree/master/pmml2tex) to convert MathML to LaTeX, in most cases, the upper and lower limits are correctly placed above and below the summation symbol. But when I convert the following MathML to LaTeX, the limits are getting placed in the sub and superscript position (as shown in the screenshot below).

**Question**: Why it's happening and how can we fix it?

**Remark**: I'm using latest edition of MiKTeX on Windows 10.

**MathML file**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
 <mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
   <mml:mrow>
     <mml:msubsup>
       <mml:mo stretchy="true">∑</mml:mo>
       <mml:mrow>
         <mml:mi>k</mml:mi>
         <mml:mo>=</mml:mo>
         <mml:mn>0</mml:mn>
       </mml:mrow>
       <mml:mrow>
         <mml:mi>n</mml:mi>
       </mml:mrow>
     </mml:msubsup>
     <mml:mrow>
       <mml:mfenced separators="|">
         <mml:mrow>
           <mml:mfrac linethickness="0pt">
             <mml:mrow>
               <mml:mi>n</mml:mi>
             </mml:mrow>
             <mml:mrow>
               <mml:mi>k</mml:mi>
             </mml:mrow>
           </mml:mfrac>
         </mml:mrow>
       </mml:mfenced>
       <mml:msup>
         <mml:mrow>
           <mml:mi>x</mml:mi>
         </mml:mrow>
         <mml:mrow>
           <mml:mi>k</mml:mi>
         </mml:mrow>
       </mml:msup>
       <mml:msup>
         <mml:mrow>
           <mml:mi>a</mml:mi>
         </mml:mrow>
         <mml:mrow>
           <mml:mi>n</mml:mi>
           <mml:mo>-</mml:mo>
           <mml:mi>k</mml:mi>
         </mml:mrow>
       </mml:msup>
     </mml:mrow>
   </mml:mrow>
 </mml:math>
```

**LaTeX generated (using David's stylesheet) from the above MathML**:

```
\[\let\par\empty

{{{{\mo{\unicode{8721}}}}\sb{{k={0}}}\sp{{n}}}{{\left({{\frac{{n}}{{k}}}}\right)}{\msup{{x}}{{k}}}{\msup{{a}}{{n-k}}}}}

\]
```

**Screenshot of the PDF generated from the above**:

[image]