# Converting MathML to LaTeX: Use of \mathop and msub tag

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, typography, mathml

When using  [David Carlisle's stylesheet](https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/tree/master/pmml2tex) to convert MathML to `LaTeX`, for some reasons, the `subscript` on an `integral` symbol seems to display noticeably farther from the integral as shown below:

**MathML**:

```
<math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mrow>
        <msubsup>
            <mo stretchy="false">∫</mo>
            <mn>0</mn>
            <mi>1</mi>
        </msubsup>
        <mrow>
            <msup>
                <mi>x</mi>
                <mi>3</mi>
            </msup>
            <mi>d</mi>
            <mi>x</mi>
        </mrow>
    </mrow>
</math>
```

**LaTeX generated by David's stylesheet** [I added the preamble to the `tex` file for testing]:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{pmml-new}
\begin{document}

\par
\[\let\par\empty
{{{{\mo{\unicode{8747}}}}\sb{{{0}}}\sp{{1}}}{{\msup{{x}}{{3}}}dx}}
\]\par

\[\let\par\empty
{{{\mathop{{\mo{\unicode{8747}}}}\sb{{{0}}}}\sp{{1}}}{{\msup{{x}}{{3}}}dx}}

\]\par

\[\int_0^1x^3dx\]

\end{document}
```

**Remarks**:

1. First typesetting above is generated from above `MathML` using David's stylesheet. Here you notice (as shown in first integral below) that the `subscript 0` is quite far away from the `integral`
2. Second typesetting above is the same as the first one but here I `manually` surrounded `{\mo{\unicode{8747}}}}\sb{{{0}}}` with `\mathop{...}`. And now you see (in the second integral below) that the `subscript 0` is very close to the integral as it should be.
3. Third typesetting above is just a plain `LaTeX` for comparison.

**Screenshot of PDF generated from above LaTeX**:

[image]

**My failed attempt**:

It seems the following portions of David's `pmm-nw.sty` and `pmm2texfrag.xsl` files are playing some role here for displaying these upper/lower limits and subscript/superscript. I `dared` to modify them but had no luck. Maybe, someone has a better idea/suggestion.

**Possible relevant portion of pmm-nw.sty file**:

```
......
\def\msub#1#2{%
  \mathop{#1}\nolimits\sb{#2}}
\def\mosub#1#2{%
  #1\nolimits\sb{#2}}
\def\msup#1#2{%
  \mathop{#1}\nolimits\sp{#2}}
\def\msubsup#1#2#3{%
  \mathop{#1}\nolimits\sb{#2}\sp{#3}}
\def\mosubsup#1#2#3{%
  #1\nolimits\sb{#2}\sp{#3}}

\def\munder#1#2{%
  \mathop{#1}\sb{#2}}
\def\mover#1#2{%
  \mathop{#1}\sp{#2}}
\def\munderover#1#2#3{%
  \mathop{#1}\sb{#2}\sp{#3}}
.....
```

**Possible relevant portion of pmm2texfrag.xsl file**:

```
<xsl:template mode="pmml2tex" match="m:mover">
 <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
 <xsl:text>\mathop{</xsl:text>
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="pmml2tex" select="*[1]"/>
 <xsl:text>}\limits</xsl:text>
 <xsl:text>\sp{</xsl:text>
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="pmml2tex" select="*[2]"/>
 <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
 <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

.....

<xsl:template mode="pmml2tex" match="m:munder">
 <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
 <xsl:text>\mathop{</xsl:text>
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="pmml2tex" select="*[1]"/>
 <xsl:text>}\limits</xsl:text>
 <xsl:text>\sb{</xsl:text>
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="pmml2tex" select="*[2]"/>
 <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
 <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template mode="pmml2tex" match="m:munderover">
 <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
 <xsl:text>\mathop{</xsl:text>
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="pmml2tex" select="*[1]"/>
 <xsl:text>}\limits</xsl:text>
 <xsl:text>\sb{</xsl:text>
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="pmml2tex" select="*[2]"/>
 <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
 <xsl:text>\sp{</xsl:text>
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="pmml2tex" select="*[3]"/>
 <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
 <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all so long ago....

But

[image]

Firstly you need to correct the namespace declaration in your source, or nothing matches at all

```xml
    <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
```

Then, really `pmml2tex` adds too many brace groups (which makes it less likely to generate tex errors but more than likely to generate poor spacing)  Here you can get rid of some of them with a custom template for integral, adding

```xml
<xsl:template mode="pmml2tex" match="m:msubsup[*[1]/self::m:mo='&#x222b;']">
 <xsl:text>\int\sb{</xsl:text>
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="pmml2tex" select="*[2]"/>
 <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
 <xsl:text>\sp{</xsl:text>
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="pmml2tex" select="*[3]"/>
 <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

to `pmml2texfrag.xsl` produces

```
\[\let\par\empty


{
\int\sb{{0}}\sp{1}
{
{\msup{x}{3}}
d
x
}
}


\]
```

which makes the above output.

Comment: Your suggestion worked like a charm. Thank you for coming to my rescue.

Comment: Some slight changes - to your suggested custom temple above - resolved the issue of my this `SO` [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/512156/22810) as well. For `summation` case, I made another copy/paste of your custom template to `pmm2texfrag.xsl` and just replaced `&#x222b;` with `&#x2211;` and `\int` with `\sum`. And now the upper/lower limits are displaying correctly above and below the summation symbol. I hope I'm doing it right for summation case.

Comment: @nam yes ideally it would automatically detect the nature of the base and do it right automatically, but not today, adding templates for the cases that you need is all I can offer today:-)